# Entity Framework TPH Inheritance Data Modeling Issues

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm new to Entity Framework and C#/.Net and trying to create a TPH inheritance model, I'm not sure if I should be or not, so if not, please advise,

Here's the model:

```
 public abstract class Vote
 {
    public int VoteID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
 }

 public class ProjectVote_ : Vote
 {
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
 }
 public class CommentVote_ : Vote //There are three more like this, votes for different hings
 {
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment Comment { get; set; }
 }
```

Now the Project model (comment and model is similar)

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vote> Vote { get; set; }
}
```

What happens is that ICollection creates a database column Project_ProjectID as the foreign key in the Vote table (I think) instead of using the ProjectID I defined. How do I fix it or should I model it differently. If the fluent API is the way to fix it, I don't know how to do that.

In the end I want to be able to use one table to store 5 different types of votes.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for the heads up John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have related entities you don't need to have a property to store the FK in your model.  Entity framework knows that it needs to make a FK to the Project table in ProjectVote when it detects Project in your ProjectVote_ model.  Same thing with User and UserId and Comment and CommentId.  You don't need to have a property that stores the FK in your model.

You are getting the FK column with the name you don't like "Project_ProjectID" because  Entity framework is detecting that it needs to create a FK for your navigation property "Project".  It's using it's own naming convention to create the column hence "Project_ProjectID".

If you want to provide your own name for the column override OnModelCreating in your DBContext class and add this fluent mapping.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Vote)
        .HasRequired(v => v.Project) //or .WithOptional(v => v.Project)
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("ProjectId"));  //or any other name you want.
}
```

And for the future [this is a helpful reference for how to use the Fluent API.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591617)  For example here is some [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.4) on how to custimize TPH with fluent.

Hope that helps!