# Insert entity with related entity in TPH architecture

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to insert an entity (`Picture`) that holds a related entity (`Ad`) based on TPH architecture:

`Picture` model:

```
public class Picture
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AdPicture : Picture
{
    public Ad Ad { get; set; }
}
```

`Ad` model:

```
public class Ad
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class AdCar : Ad
{
    public int? CubicCapacity { get; set; }
    public int? Power { get; set; }
}
```

I want to insert a new `Picture` in the `AdCar`, and I tried:

```
AdPicture picture = new AdPicture()
{
    Ad = _adRepository.GetById(adId),
    Filename = newFileName
};

_pictureService.CreateAdPicture(picture);
```

CreateAdPicture:

```
public void CreateAdPicture(AdPicture adPicture)
{
    _adPictureRepository.Add(adPicture);
    _adPictureRepository.Save();
}
```

But Entity Framework says

> *Invalid column name 'AdCar_Id'.*

When I check the SQL command text, I can see

```
insert [dbo].[Pictures]([Name], [Filename], [URL], [Rank], [Discriminator], [PictureType_Id], [AdCar_Id], [Ad_Id])
values (null, @0, null, @1, @2, @3, @4, null)
```

It's putting `AdCar_Id` and `Ad_Id`, why? How can I insert the `Picture` related with the `AdCar`?

Answer (score 0):

**First up:** You may need to define the key for the subclass explicitly to be `Ad_Id` as it is assuming the `AdCar_Id` (or vice-versa).

Something like this in your DbContext:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<AdPicture>()
            .HasRequired(o => o.Ad)
            .WithMany().Map(f => f.MapKey("Ad_Id"));
```

**Second:** Also, just to check - all of these classes have completely separate tables (TPH) and not tables with just the additional properties specified (TPH) I.e. an AdPicture does not have data in both a Picture and AdPicture table?

Having not done TPH (only TPT) I am unsure of if Entity Framework handles the subclass-ing differently, but I suspect it must. Someone else can hopefully answer that better if you are missing something there.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using Fluent code yet, can I do this in the Model definition in another way? AdPicture and Picture are in the same table where the field "Discriminator" defines the class associated with each record.

Comment: So both should be using the Ad_Id?

Comment: I only know how to do this with fluent - I know there are some things that can only be done with Fluent, but am not sure this is one of them. This post describes it well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248410/entity-framework-tph-inheritance-data-modeling-issues

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

I was defining the Navigation property "public IList Pictures { get; set; }" in the Ad Model that was creating an aditional field in the SQL Command "Ad_Id".

As soon as I removed it, the problem was solved and all the theory I had about TPH came togheter again :)

Thanks for your feedback.